# C++ dll and WPF

Tags: wpf, dll, c++-cli

```
[DllImport("Project1.dll")]
unsafe static extern void CallFu(string OpenFile, string SaveFile);
```

This is dll on C++
The Function get image file string do smth and save new image to SaveFile string.

```
extern "C" void __export __stdcall CallFu(char* filepath,char* savefilepath)
```

Then i try to put saved image to ImageControl

```
string save = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\segmentedKletka.bmp";
private void B_AutoSegm_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string open = MainWindow.OsnovnoyClassPict.Pict_Source;
        CallFu(open, save);

        BitmapImage s_bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(save));

        Slider_Kletka.Maximum = Slider_Yadro.Maximum = s_bmp.Width;
        Slider_Kletka.Value = Slider_Yadro.Value = s_bmp.Width / 2;
        Slider_Kletka.IsEnabled = Slider_Yadro.IsEnabled = true;

        Img_Kletka.Source = Img_Yadro.Source = s_bmp;

                }
```

and here i get the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArithmeticException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Переполнение или потеря точности в арифметической операции.  (Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.)

How use c++ dll in WPF correctly?

```
        [DllImport("Project1.dll")]
        unsafe static extern void CallFu(string OpenFile, string SaveFile);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string open = "D:\\SPPR_Gem\\SPPRGem\\bin\\Release\\kletki\\1a2a917d-45379cc5-451b3e95-a20e772c.bmp";
            string save = "D:\\Projects\\SPPRGem\\SPPRGem\\bin\\Release\\segmentedKletka.bmp";
            CallFu(open, save);
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(save);
        }
```

This is in c# only. And i have no errors.

P.S. sorry for my bad english =)

Comment: have you tried calling the same method with the same exact file paths within a C++ project?

Comment: could you please edit to include the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a31f9c7a-0e15-4a09-a544-bec07f0f152c